# Fact dimesion/ Degenerated dimension

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008, ssas-2012, degenerate-dimension

Is there any alternative of fact relationship?
How to get rid of de-generated dimension / fact relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You can make two tables in the data source view from the one table, a dimension and a fact table.